# SQL Server query - Insert @space by using space button

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am currently doing a stored procedure with parameter, when I insert data by typing space shown at below with replicate format to make the result.

```
declare @space varchar(200)
select @space = replicate(' ',200)
select Len(@C)
```

Unfortunately, the result is 0 when execute the query

```
@space
-------
0
```

but typing a instead of space is work as len of @space have 200.

Is there any idea how to make the `@space` len to 200 by using space as data?

```
@space
------
200
```

Comment: I will concluded the different of DATALENGTH and LEN , LEN will not count the space data when end of data is space which like nothing and the result will be 0 , in between of data have space. it will count the data in. As for DATALENGTH , it will count type of key you put in even if it space at end of the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [DATALENGTH (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

```
declare @space varchar(200)
select @space = replicate(' ',200)
select Len(@space),DATALENGTH(@space)
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/4179)

From [LEN (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

> Returns the number of characters of the specified string expression,
>   **excluding trailing blanks**.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
DECLARE @space VARCHAR(200)
SELECT @space = REPLICATE(' ', 200)
SELECT LEN(@space + '_') - 1
SELECT DATALENGTH(@space)
```